# bilinear interpolation with extract(): show intermediate steps

Tags: r, r-raster

I use extract() to get bilinear interpolated points out of my raster-object. Is there a way to show intermediate steps of the interpolation? I would be interested in the coordinates and values of the nearest four grid-points and the distances to my interpolation point.

With r = raster(...) and spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame() my function call is the following:

```
out <- extract(r, spdf, method="bilinear")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the code in `raster:::.bilinearValue` line by line, with `raster = r`; xyCoords = `coordinates(spdf)`; `layer=1`, `n=1`